# Черный фон вместо прозрачности Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Появилась очень странная проблема. Дело в том, что когда я просматриваю некоторые изображения в Android Studio, (в т.ч. это всегда белые иконки Material Design), вместо их прозрачного фона - чернота. Везде, где только можно: в редакторе лейаута, просто при просмотре во вкладке и даже в предпросмотре в **винде**(!). А в предпросмотре меню, так вообще не появляется картинка.

[image: В открытой вкладке] [image: В редакторе] [image: В винде] [image: Редактор Меню]

В то же время, после билда, на тестовом устройстве, все как надо.

[image: Меню] [image: Кнопка]

Кто-то сталкивался? Проблема хоть и не критичная, но очень раздражает.

Comment: вас не устраивает темная тема самой студии или тема приложения самостоятельно изменяется?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko по-моему, я пояснил в начале, что речь идет о **фоне изображений**, которые на скриншотах продемонстрированы в виде кнопки и пункта меню.

Comment: а вы пробовали переустановить студию? может иконки косячные какие-то? в это слабо верится, но мне кажется что вы уже все перепробовали перед тем как сюда идти

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko не переустанавливал, ибо такая же хрень на другом компе бывает. Это происходит примерно с двумя из десяти белых иконок с прозрачным фоном. С остальными все нормально.

Мне кажется, косяк в винде, ибо в ней ведь тоже в проводнике прозрачный фон становится черным

Comment: может при добавлении в дравабл изменить цвет вручную? либо второй вариант - закачать пак этих иконок с сайта разработчиков и не заморачиваться, у студии есть куча глюков

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дк я оттуда и скачиваю. Я не понимаю, вы правильно хоть поняли суть моей проблемы? На устройстве все нормально, это **именно, что баг** с проедпросмотром либо студии либо чего-то еще

Comment: возможно я не очень правильно понял суть вашего вопроса, не спорю)) если и на другом компе такое, то все очень странно